# xml content does not seem to be xml

Tags: r, web-scraping, html-parsing

Trying to retrieve some information from r-users.com. I'm using the following code and I receive the warning message:

> ```
> XML content does not seem to be XML
> ```

Any help would be appreciated.

```
library(data.table)
library(XML)

pages <- c(1:10)

urls <- rbindlist (lapply(pages, function(x) {
  url <- paste("https://www.r-users.com/jobs/page/",x,"/", sep="")
  data.frame(url)
}), fill=TRUE)

jobLocations <- rbindlist (apply(urls, 1, function(url) {
  doc1 <- htmlParse (url)
  locations <- getNodeSet(doc1, '//*[@id="mainContent"]/div[2]/ol/li/dl/dd[3]/span')
  data.frame(sapply(locations, function(x) { xmlValue(x) }))
  }), fill = TRUE)
```

Comment: If I access a URL and view the source e.g. https://www.r-users.com/jobs/page/1/ there is no XML contained on the page (although it may be loading XML in the background to get tot hat result).  I suspect your error is correct, you're parsing HTML, not XML.

Answer (score 1):

rvest and purrr is a powerful combination for web scraping:

```
library(rvest)
library(purrr)

             # make URLs
locations <- 1:10 %>% paste0("https://www.r-users.com/jobs/page/", .) %>%
    # pull and parse HTML for each URL
    map(read_html) %>%
    # select nodes for each page's HTML
    map(html_nodes, xpath = '//*[@id="mainContent"]/div[2]/ol/li/dl/dd[3]/span') %>%
    # return text inside of each node
    map(html_text) %>%
    # simplify list to vector
    simplify()

head(locations)
## [1] "Massachusetts, United States" "New York, United States"      "England, United Kingdom"     
## [4] "California, United States"    "Ontario, Canada"              "Indiana, United States"
```